# Laravel eloquent sum relationship quantity and groupby

Tags: laravel, eloquent

### products Table:

```
id        name
1     first product
```

### product_credits table:

```
id   product_id   quantity
1         1          10
2         1          20
```

### What I am trying to do:

I am trying to get all the ***products quantities***.

### Expected data:

Get the:

- product name = first product
- product quantity = 30

### Model Relationship code:

```
public function credits () {
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Models\Product\ProductCredits')
        -> whereHas('importInvoice', function ($query) {
            $query->where('deleted_at', null);
        }) -> orderBy('created_at', 'ASC') -> orderBy('quantity', 'DESC');
}
```

The relationship works good.

### What I have tried:

I have tried to use `with` function in the eloquent.

```
public function exportProductsCredit(Request $request) {
    // GET THE COLLECTION
    $products = Product::with(['credits' => function ($query) {
        $query -> where('quantity', '>', 1) -> groupBy('product_id') -> sum('quantity');
    }]) -> get();

    return $products;
}
```

But it throw an error: `product_credits.id' isn't in GROUP BY`

### EDIT

Problem is that I have `Mutator` fields that I want to show for example I calculate the `product_net_price` which I return as a mutator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it as an attribute, dont try to query build it like a relation.

you can declare the attribute like this in `Product::class`

```
public function getSumCreditsAttribute()
{
    return $this->credits->where('quantity', '>', 1)->sum('quantity');
}
```

you can also always have it loaded with the `appends` attribute

```
protected $appends = ['sum_credits'];
```

or access it when you have an instance of `Product::class`

```
$products = Product::get();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    var_dump($product->sum_credits);
}
```

Comment: That is a good solution but like this whenever i call the `Product` model it will return with it the `sum_credits` right? I dont want it like this

Comment: @Danny if you dont put the `sum_credits` inthe $append attribute, it wont be loaded until you try to access it via `->sum_credits`. you can verify that with a `dd('product')`.

Comment: That is a good solution and it will help me in all upcoming reports. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't achieve group by & aggregate out of the box using model. You need to use the following way

```
Product::join('product_credits as pc', 'products.id', '=', 'pc.product_id')
        ->select('products.id', 'products.name', DB::raw("SUM(pc.quantity) as 'product_quantity'"))
        ->with('credits')
        ->where('pc.quantity', '>', 1)
        ->groupBy('pc.product_id')
        ->get();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It throw an error say `quantity.id column not found` I have changed it to  `quantity` but still not working

Comment: I am trying to use `Mutator` to append the fields in my eloquent but I am facing a problem where whenever i call the `Product` model it will return the mutator fields

Comment: Also you solution does not return the mutator fields that I want to show..

Comment: As far as I tested in local. I can access those Mutators in the controller as well as in view.